# How to catch result set in code view

Tags: vb.net, stored-procedures

I created this stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PersonAssign
(
    @PersonID int
)
BEGIN
    Update Register set Status = 'true' where PersonID = @PersonID;
    SELECT * FROM Register
END
```

Now, I want to get result set in vb.net by using ADO.net. How can I catch this. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably create a sqlcommand object, connect to the database, executeReader and return a sqldatareader object.   There a bunch of other ways to do this depending on what you want to do with the data.  Please be more specific if you aren't looking for a general idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 Dim con As New SqlConnection
 Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
 Dim dr As New SqlDataReader()
 Try
  con.ConnectionString = Settings.ConnectionString
  con.Open()
  cmd.Connection = con
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
  cmd.CommandText = "PersonAssign"
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@PersonID", SqlDbType.Int)
  cmd.Parameters("@PersonID").Value = -Parameter-value-
  dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

  ' Do something with dr
Catch e As Exception
End Try
```